# MonoTouch: StoryBoarding - manual segues?

Tags: mono, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, storyboard

iPhone/iPad dev newb here...

I am using MonoTouch to create a universal iPad/iPhone storyboard app.  In the primary view controller (RootViewController) the default auto-generated behavior is a table with a single cell "Detail" in it, which hardwires you to the next destination (DetailViewController).

I'd like to change this RootViewController to instead show a login control I've made extending UIViewController (LoginView).  I have had some success putting the LoginView inside the RootViewController, but can't figure out how to make it 'segue' to DetailViewController.  And upon watching how the iPad app works, where there is no segue (that I can see) between the two, am I going about this wrong?

To summarize: How do I enhance this storyboard app with a preceding login screen, reusing its contents/xib between the iPad and iPhone variant?

Apologies if this is a bit unclear and muddled.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried a storyboard app in Monotouch yet, but I did spend a lot of time working out the best approach for a login screen for my application. What I ended up doing, which could work in your situation as well, is presenting the login screen as a Modal view. Once the user has successfully logged in, we then push the next appropriate view.

So if you are automatically pushed into the detail view by the storyboard viewcontroller, you could display the login dialog as a modal dialog from the detail view's DidLoad or DidAppear methods.